# How to make a link with a .apk extension a .php page

Tags: php

What I want to do is make a link (for example http://site.com/download.zip ) go to a file named download.php with keeping the same extension looking like an zip file, performing some code, and then redirecting the user to the actual zip file.

I'm not sure if what I'm trying so say clear, so let me know if I need to elaborate more.

What I found is that I could possibly use

AddHandler application/x-httpd-php .zip

but then I wouldn't know how to let it actually download the zip after redirecting.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Depending on your exact setup, and the URL you would like to use, I would suggest mod_rewrite

```
RewriteRule /(.+)\.zip downloadscript.php [NC,L]
```

Then have the php file redirect to the real file location (/download/download.zip)

```
header("Location: /download/download.zip");
```

This will send any request for *.zip in / to /downloadscript.php, the .zip files in /download/ will work fine.